# Media supported by Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

It seems as if Chromecast is an implementation of Google Cast. As any implementation it can support more media than minimally required. I was able to play the following media that is not mentioned in the Google Cast SDK:

- WAV file
- Ogg Vorbis file
- x264 movie in a Matroska container

Are there other containers and media format that Chromecast supports that are not mentioned in  the Google Cast SDK?

Comment: This probably is a question for /SuperUser rather than /StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully playing back H264 Video / AAC Audio that is in a Matroska container.

I've also successfully tested a WAV file (http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11k16bitpcm.wav), and an Ogg Vorbis audio file (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg)